# Symfony notifier attach custom metadata to envelope

Tags: php, symfony, messenger

I'm using the Symfony notifier and messenger components to asynchronously send SMS messages (and in the future push and email notifications).

Everything works just fine, however once a message is sent, I'd like to log information about it.

I can catch a successful message by subscribing to `WorkerMessageHandledEvent` which provides me the `Message` object, along with the containing `Envelope` and all its `Stamp` objects inside. From all the available information, I'll be logging this in my database using an entity named `MessageLog`.

```php
class MessengerSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            WorkerMessageHandledEvent::class => ['onHandled']
        ];
    }

    public function onHandled(WorkerMessageHandledEvent $event) {
        $log = new MessageLog();
        $log->setSentAt(new DateTime());

        if($event->getEnvelope()->getMessage() instanceof SmsMessage) {
            $log->setSubject($event->getEnvelope()->getMessage()->getSubject());
            $log->setRecipient($event->getEnvelope()->getMessage()->getPhone());
        }

        // Do more tracking
    }

}
```

What I'd like to do, is track the object that "invoked" the message. For example, if I have a news feed, and posting a post sends out a notification, I'd like to attribute each logged message to that post (to display audience reach/delivery stats per post - and from an admin POV auditing and reporting).

I've tried to go about adding a `Stamp`, or other means of trying to attach custom metadata to the message, but it seems to be abstracted when using the `symfony/notifier` bundle.

The below is what I'm using to send notifications (more or less WIP):

```php
class PostService {

    protected NotifierInterface $notifier;

    public function ___construct(NotifierInterface $notifier) {
        $this->notifier = $notifier;
    }

    public function sendNotifications(Post $post) {
        $notification = new PostNotification($post);
        
        $recipients = [];
        foreach($post->getNewsFeed()->getSubscribers() as $user) {
            $recipients[] = new Recipient($user->getEmail(), $user->getMobilePhone());
        }

        $this->notifier->send($notification, ...$recipients);
    }

}
```

```php
class PostNotification extends Notification implements SmsNotificationInterface {

    protected Post $post;

    public function __construct(Post $post) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function getChannels(RecipientInterface $recipient): array {
        return ['sms'];
    }

    public function asSmsMessage(SmsRecipientInterface $recipient, string $transport = null): ?SmsMessage {
        if($transport === 'sms') {
            return new SmsMessage($recipient->getPhone(), $this->getPostContentAsSms());
        }

        return null;
    }

    private function getPostContentAsSms() {
        return $post->getTitle()."\n\n".$post->getContent();
    }

}
```

By the time this is all done, this is all I have in the `WorkerMessageHandledEvent`

```
^ Symfony\Component\Messenger\Event\WorkerMessageHandledEvent^ {#5590
  -envelope: Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope^ {#8022
    -stamps: array:7 [
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\BusNameStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\BusNameStamp^ {#10417
          -busName: "messenger.bus.default"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Doctrine\Transport\DoctrineReceivedStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Doctrine\Transport\DoctrineReceivedStamp^ {#10419
          -id: "2031"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\TransportMessageIdStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\TransportMessageIdStamp^ {#10339
          -id: "2031"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ReceivedStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ReceivedStamp^ {#5628
          -transportName: "async"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ConsumedByWorkerStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ConsumedByWorkerStamp^ {#7306}
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\AckStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\AckStamp^ {#7159
          -ack: Closure(Envelope $envelope, Throwable $e = null)^ {#6205
            class: "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Worker"
            this: Symfony\Component\Messenger\Worker {#5108 …}
            use: {
              $transportName: "async"
              $acked: & false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\HandledStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\HandledStamp^ {#11445
          -result: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SentMessage^ {#2288
            -original: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\NullMessage^ {#6625
              -decoratedMessage: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage^ {#10348
                -transport: null
                -subject: ".................................................."
                -phone: "0412345678"
              }
            }
            -transport: "null"
            -messageId: null
          }
          -handlerName: "Symfony\Component\Notifier\Messenger\MessageHandler::__invoke"
        }
      ]
    ]
    -message: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage^ {#10348}
  }
  -receiverName: "async"
}
```

The doco shows me ways to add my own stamps to the envelope, which I'm guessing I can use to attach metadata such as my `Post` object, but this means I need to use the `MessageBusInterface` to send notifications. I don't want to do because I would like to route messages through the `NotifierInterface` to gain all the benefits of channel policies, texter transports, etc.

---

tl;dr: how do I get some metadata through to a `WorkerMessageHandledEvent` if I send a message using the `NotifierInterface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to make it work!

Essentially what happens is that we have two components here, the Symfony *notifier* and the Symfony *messenger*. When used together, they create a powerful way to send messages to any number of endpoints.

Firstly what I did was create an interface called `NotificationStampsInterface` and a trait called `NotificationStamps` that satisfies the interface (by storing a protected array using the interface methods to read/write to it).

```php
class NotificationStampsInterface {
    
    public function getStamps(): array;

    public function addStamp(StampInterface $stamp);

    public function removeStamp(StampInterface $stamp);
}
```

This interface can then be added onto your custom notification object, in this instance `PostNotification`, alongside with the `NotificationStamps` trait to satisfy the interface methods.

The trick here is that when sending a notification via the notifier, it ultimately calls on the messenger component to send the message. The bit that handles this is `Symfony\Component\Notifier\Channel\SmsChannel`. Essentially, if a MessageBus is available, it will push messages through that rather than going straight though the notifier.

We can extend the `SmsChannel` class to add our own logic inside `notify()` method.

```php
class SmsNotify extends \Symfony\Component\Notifer\Channel\SmsChannel {
   
    public function notify(Notification $notification, RecipientInterface $recipient, string $transportName = null): void {
        $message = null;
        if ($notification instanceof SmsNotificationInterface) {
            $message = $notification->asSmsMessage($recipient, $transportName);
        }

        if (null === $message) {
            $message = SmsMessage::fromNotification($notification, $recipient);
        }

        if (null !== $transportName) {
            $message->transport($transportName);
        }

        if (null === $this->bus) {
            $this->transport->send($message);
        } else {
            // New logic
            if($notification instanceof NotificationStampsInterface) {
                $envelope = Envelope::wrap($message, $notification->getStamps());
                $this->bus->dispatch($envelope);
            } else {
                $this->bus->dispatch($message);
            }

            // Old logic
            // $this->bus->dispatch($message);
        }
    }
   
}
```

Lastly we need to override the service by adding the following in `services.yaml`

```yaml
    notifier.channel.sms:
        class: App\Notifier\Channel\SmsChannel
        arguments: ['@texter.transports', '@messenger.default_bus']
        tags:
            - { name: notifier.channel, channel: sms }
```

---

And that's it! We now have a way to append stamps to our Notification object that will carry all the way through to the `WorkerMessageHandledEvent`.

An example use would be (for my situation at least)

```php
class RelatedEntityStamp implements StampInterface {

    private string $className;
    private int $classId;

    public function __construct(object $entity) {
        $this->className = get_class($entity);
        $this->classId = $entity->getId();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getClassName(): string {
        return $this->className;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getClassId(): int {
        return $this->classId;
    }

}
```

```php
class PostService {

    protected NotifierInterface $notifier;

    public function ___construct(NotifierInterface $notifier) {
        $this->notifier = $notifier;
    }

    public function sendNotifications(Post $post) {
        $notification = new PostNotification($post);
        $stamp = new RelatedEntityStamp($post);        // Solution
        $notification->addStamp($stamp);               // Solution
        
        $recipients = [];
        foreach($post->getNewsFeed()->getSubscribers() as $user) {
            $recipients[] = new Recipient($user->getEmail(), $user->getMobilePhone());
        }

        $this->notifier->send($notification, ...$recipients);
    }

}
```

Once the message is sent, dumping the result shows that we do indeed have our stamp registered at the point where our event fires.

```
^ Symfony\Component\Messenger\Event\WorkerMessageHandledEvent^ {#1078
  -envelope: Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope^ {#1103
    -stamps: array:8 [
      "App\Notification\Stamp\RelatedEntityStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => App\Notification\Stamp\RelatedEntityStamp^ {#1062
          -className: "App\Entity\Post"
          -classId: 207
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\BusNameStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\BusNameStamp^ {#1063
          -busName: "messenger.bus.default"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Doctrine\Transport\DoctrineReceivedStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Bridge\Doctrine\Transport\DoctrineReceivedStamp^ {#1066
          -id: "2590"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\TransportMessageIdStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\TransportMessageIdStamp^ {#1067
          -id: "2590"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ReceivedStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ReceivedStamp^ {#1075
          -transportName: "async"
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ConsumedByWorkerStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\ConsumedByWorkerStamp^ {#1076}
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\AckStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\AckStamp^ {#1077
          -ack: Closure(Envelope $envelope, Throwable $e = null)^ {#1074
            class: "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Worker"
            this: Symfony\Component\Messenger\Worker {#632 …}
            use: {
              $transportName: "async"
              $acked: & false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
      "Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\HandledStamp" => array:1 [
        0 => Symfony\Component\Messenger\Stamp\HandledStamp^ {#1101
          -result: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SentMessage^ {#1095
            -original: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\NullMessage^ {#1091
              -decoratedMessage: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage^ {#1060
                -transport: null
                -subject: ".................................................."
                -phone: "0412345678"
              }
            }
            -transport: "null"
            -messageId: null
          }
          -handlerName: "Symfony\Component\Notifier\Messenger\MessageHandler::__invoke"
        }
      ]
    ]
    -message: Symfony\Component\Notifier\Message\SmsMessage^ {#1060}
  }
  -receiverName: "async"
}
```